# Key value to turn on or off the website maintenance mode always redirects to maintenance page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-8

According to the below link I created a key value to turn on or off the website maintenance mode.

But the problem I am facing is even if I set the key value to off still all requests are redirecting to my maintenance page.

[Put the website in Maintenance Mode](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/219637/Put-the-website-in-Maintanance-Mode-Under-Construc)

Here is my code :

Golbal.asax:

```
 public void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaintenanceMode"] == "true")
        {
          //  if (!Request.IsLocal)
          //  {
                HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("Error.htm");
           // }
        }
    }
```

web.config :

```
 <add key="MaintenanceMode" value="false"/>
```

Comment: Post your code, you may have typo or something else in your version vs. what is in an article you are trying to use.

Comment: Sorry I missed to add my code. Please see my code now.

Comment: Why not use [app_offline.htm](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/426755)?

Comment: If I use app_offline my entire application goes offline. I don't want to do that.

Comment: This is definitely weird, could you post larger portion of the `Web.config` file? Could you use debugger to check the value of `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaintenanceMode"]` at runtime?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.rewritepath?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)--which I don't really have time to test and confirm--this method returns a redirect to the browser, so either the browser or a proxy may be caching the redirect. Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: @KennethK. Thanks for letting me know this point. the browser is caching the redirect. When I clear the browser cache it works perfectly.